# How to create bin for each column automatically

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below

```
date           A    B  ...    Z    
2014-12-01     22   33 ...    44  
2014-12-02     33   44 ...    55  
.  
.  
2014-12-30     65   75 ...    85
```

I can calculate bin for each column with below code

```
df$A_Bin<-cut(df$A, breaks = c(0, seq(1, 1000, by = 5)), labels = 0:199)    
df$B_Bin<-cut(df$B, breaks = c(0, seq(1, 1000, by = 5)), labels = 0:199)
```

How to automat above code

```
o/p   
date           A    B  ...    Z    A_Bin  B_bin  ... Z_Bin  
2014-12-01     22   33 ...    44   5       7     ... 9  
2014-12-02     33   44 ...    55   7       9     ... 11
.  
.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` from `base R`

```
df[paste0(names(df)[-1], "_Bin")] <- lapply(df[-1], cut, 
          breaks = c(0, seq(1, 1000, by = 5), labels = 0:199)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may write a function that bins a single vector:

```
myBins <- function(x) cut(x, breaks = c(0, seq(1, 1000, by = 5)), labels = 0:199)
```

Then apply it to columns of your your data frame, except for column 1:

```
binned <- sapply(df[,-1], myBins)
```

Name it's columns:

```
colnames(binned) <- paste0(LETTERS, "_Bin")
```

And add result to original `df`:

```
newdf <- cbind(df, binned)
```

Comment: after running colnames(binned) am getting error Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent .. Thanks

Comment: Maybe columns of your original df are not named with all the letters (A to Z)?

Comment: colnames(binned) <- paste("Bin", colnames(binned), sep = "_") i got it through this. thanks .am adding prefix